# Used CURL to get NodeJS, how to remove the files (have not installed nodeJS yet though)

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, curl

I used: `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo -E bash -` because I wanted to install NodeJS, but after executing the command - I realised I used the wrong command. I need NodeJS version 5, not 4.

I have not used `apt-get install nodejs` yet. How can I remove the files that the first command downloaded, so that I can execute a different curl command and then install NodeJS using `apt-get install nodejs` ?

I'm rather new to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By piping to `| sudo -E bash -`, you executed the code from `https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x`, which is a bash script.

Looking at the script it appears to add:

```
print_status 'Creating apt sources list file for the NodeSource Node.js 4.x LTS Argon repo...' 
exec_cmd "echo 'deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_4.x ${DISTRO} main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list"
exec_cmd "echo 'deb-src https://deb.nodesource.com/node_4.x ${DISTRO} main' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list"
print_status 'Running `apt-get update` for you...'
exec_cmd 'apt-get update'
```

So you can remove the sources, but if you run the 5.x script, it will just replace this file, so either running the same script with 5.x instead of 4.x or removing the file and then running the 5.x script will give you the same result:

```
$ curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_5.x | sudo -E bash -
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list
deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_5.x wily main
deb-src https://deb.nodesource.com/node_5.x wily main
```

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question perfectly, with additional explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the script, nothing much installs, until you run apt-get install nodejs.

```
PRE_INSTALL_PKGS=""

if [ ! -e /usr/lib/apt/methods/https ]; then
    PRE_INSTALL_PKGS="${PRE_INSTALL_PKGS} apt-transport-https"
fi

if [ ! -x /usr/bin/lsb_release ]; then
    PRE_INSTALL_PKGS="${PRE_INSTALL_PKGS} lsb-release"
fi

if [ ! -x /usr/bin/curl ] && [ ! -x /usr/bin/wget ]; then
    PRE_INSTALL_PKGS="${PRE_INSTALL_PKGS} curl"
fi
```

Nothing in there would I worry about.  Then as the script continues, it adds the PPA.

```
exec_cmd "echo 'deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_4.x ${DISTRO} main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list"
exec_cmd "echo 'deb-src https://deb.nodesource.com/node_4.x ${DISTRO} main' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list"
```

I would remove nodesource.list from apt/sources.list.d/

```
sudo rm /etc/sources.list.d/nodesource.list
```

Then apt-get update

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply. When I use `sudo apt-get update` after I have deleted the files you told me to... Will it install Node? Or will I have to run the second curl command to curl version 5?

Comment: You will need to run the initial installation command for version 5. -- 'curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_5.x | bash -'